# Named URL Pattern Throwing NoReverseMatch Exception

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm implementing the canonical books/authors/publishers example in Django 1.4.  In my view that shows a list of all books, I've inserted a url template tag into an anchor tag that refers to a named URL pattern:

```
{% for book in book_list %}
    {# <a href="/book/{{ book.id }}/">{{ book.title }}</a> #}
    <a href="{% url 'book-details' book.id %}">{{ book.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

(Note that I've commented out the hard-coded URL anchor which *does* work.)

My urlpatterns are:

```
url(r'^book/$', 'app.views.show_all_books', name="all-books"),
url(r'^book/(\d+)/$', 'app.views.show_book_details', name="book-details"),
```

When I click on the anchor to view a book's details, I get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /book/
Reverse for "book-details" with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

I've read other posts on here about others who've had this error as well as the Django docs on the url template tag and naming URL patterns but I don't see what I'm doing wrong.  If it will help, here's the signature for the 'show_book_details' function:

```
def show_book_details(request, id):
```

I guess I don't completely understand what the error message is telling me.  I've tried removing the single quotes around the urlpattern name and I've also tried using the viewpath 'app.views.show_book_details' instead of the named urlpattern but neither change solves the problem.  Can someone help?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes from the url tag in your template:

```
{% url book-details book.id %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url

Comment: Thank you. I was looking at the development version of the documentation, not v. 1.4 as you showed.  The dev version shows quote marks.  My bad.